# operator norm of inverse of a bounded operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$ T: X \to X $ is one to one bounded linear operator or equavallently  $$||T||= \sup \{ ||Tx|| : ||x||=1 \}< \infty $$ and $$T^{-1} : T(X) \to X $$ exists.

Now I want to prove that $$||T^{-1}||^{-1} = \inf \{||Tx|| :|| x||=1 \}$$

Can some help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general. Indeed, let $X=\ell^\infty$ and define
$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(x_1,\tfrac{x_2}2,\tfrac{x_3}3,\ldots).$$
Then it can be shown $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ and $\|T\|=1$. However, the inverse is given by
$$T^{-1}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,2x_2,\ldots)$$
which is not bounded.

If we are to assume $X$ is Banach **and** $T$ has closed image then $T^{-1}$ is bounded by the open mapping theorem, however we usually do not have any relation between $\|T\|$ and $\|T^{-1}\|$.